# Does vertex-centric indexes support string search predicates in JanusGraph?

Tags: tinkerpop3, janusgraph, janus

I want to index a JSON(string) as vertex-centric index. My use case is that I want to match regex predicates in this string. Will vertex-centric indexes support ***textRegex***

I am following this link for checking string search in Janus: https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/search-predicates/#text-predicate

For example: If my string property is {"foo":"bar"}, I want to regex search for property "foo" in this string property.